# What's the name of this beetle?

Tags: zoology, entomology, species-identification

I found him in a kitchen located in Toronto, Ontario, Canada.

[image: Mysterious bug on a piece of paper.]
[image: Mysterious bug on a piece of wood.]
[image: Mysterious bug scurrying away.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks very similar to a [click beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_beetle). Some of them are pretty popular in south Canada.

Comment: Lay the beetle on its back. If it inverts itself using a strong clicking action then you have yourself a click beetle.

Comment: @docscience I can't, I already released it a few days ago. But the image on the Wikipedia page looks very similar so I'll assume that's what it was.